# No Indian (and Bengali) keyboard layout in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus, input-language

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 today. I'm from Bangladesh, and Bengali is my native language. There was an option to set keyboard layout to Bengali in all previous Ubuntu versions I've used. But there's no such option in 17.04, strangely. I can use Bengali by installing the package `ibus-m17n`,  so I thought maybe there was some problem during my upgrade. But then I checked my friend's PC which runs ubuntu 16.10 and found that `ibus-m17n` was not installed in 16.10 but there's option for Bengali keyboard layout. So is Bengali keyboard support really removed from 17.04, or was there a problem during my upgrade?

Comment: Which layout were you using or interested to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Bangla keyboard layouts seem to have been [hidden intentionally](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/commit/?id=913af7dafaab8ff4a9ae0d1e4c4097caf4a8022d) in version 2.19 of the `xkb-data` package, which is the one shipped with Ubuntu 17.04. You know better than me whether the reasoning behind that measure is reasonable. (I'd be interested to hear your view.)

Anyway, they are hidden and not dropped. If you open a terminal window and run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
```

the Bangla layouts should be shown in the user interface again.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I don't understand why developer hide it default without any alternatives !

Comment: @shantanu: Which Ubuntu flavor are you using? Please follow the link I provided to see how they motivated the measure.

Comment: I first used your command, but couldn't get any layout. Then I read OP's question again and installed `ibus-m17n` package, which made the layouts appear in the list. Then I reverted your command and the layouts were still there. I think OP can use the layouts by installing the package too. So, I think you may want to include something about the package. Also if there was some packaging changes involved other than the hiding, since in 16.10, the layouts were there even without that package!

Comment: @Anwar: What appear, if you install `ibus-m17n`, are the Bengali input methods, not the XKB keyboard layouts. They are separate things. Since the OP already mentioned `ibus-m17n` in the question, I see no reason to repeat it in the answer. The question is about the XKB layouts, and the change between 16.10 and 17.04 was in the `xkb-data` package.

Comment: I think hiding the keyboard layouts is stupid. Particularly when `ibus-m17n` is not installed by default.

Comment: @user68186: Yes, it's stupid. I just filed [bug #1707929](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1707929).