# how to type in malayalam in ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, language-support

i could install malayalam language from system settings>language support. but then when i go to system settings>text entry, malayalam is not showing up in the "select an input source to add"

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904769/no-bengali-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu-17-04). It applies to Malayalam too.