# Writing Hindi language with Bolnagri in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, 17.04

In earlier versions of Ubuntu there used to be bolnagri keymap but in Ubuntu 17.04 it is not there. As bolnagri keymap was very comfortable to user I want it to install Ubuntu 17.04 as this [link](http://www.indlinux.org/wiki/index.php/BolNagri) is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hindi (Bolnagri)* is still there, but it was hidden. Please see the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/904769). The suggested solution will 'unhide' *Hindi (Bolnagri)* as well.

Comment: Thanks. I suggest we treat this question as a duplicate. This answer is "link only" as it does not give us the basic steps to correct the problem.  I will change the title of the question you link to, to reflect its general applicability.

Comment: But @user68186 you cannot generalize as the linked question may have same answer but the point of question is different.

Comment: @user68186: Well, that's one way to handle it. The problem is that the issue affects quite a few Indian keyboard layouts, and not all of them are mentioned at the other question. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/941437) is another example, and there are more.

Comment: I suspect it affects all Indian language keyboard layouts as the commit refers to Indian keyboard layout. Other South Asian languages like Sinhalese (Sri Lanka) may have similar problems but they may not be affected. I can't check this as I am on Ubuntu 16.04. Bengali is affected as it is spoken in India and Bangladesh.

Comment: I searched all the Indian language names I could think of and found a few questions. You have commented and linked to the original Bengali question is some of them. I have marked them all as possible duplicates.