# Ubuntu MATE 17.10 does not have Malayalam in Text Entry

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language, malayalam

Recently I have installed Ubuntu MATE 17.10 b2. But in text entry keyboard layout, I could not see Malayalam. I tried some solutions found on the internet, but problem is still there (Malayalam is not there).

#### What I have tried:

1. I used the command

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
   ```

   but could not select Malayalam.
2. I installed Malayalam language through language support, still not showing Malayalam layout.
3. Installed Ibus and m17n packages but still no Malayalam is there.
4. I did reboots and reinstall.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: To the close voter: I know the explanation, and posted an answer. Think it may be useful, since there was an annoyance wrt to Indic languages in 17.04, so let's not close the question even if 17.10 hasn't been released yet.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The reason this is going to get closed anyways is because the developers need to be aware of the bug, not us. Working around is not a valid solution. The devs need to know and issue a patch so that this problem won't affect more users. If this is an issue with 17.04 as well, that should be its own question.

Comment: Problem resolved after upgrade

Comment: @KazWolfe: You misunderstood. The issue has already been fixed (by me, actually), but it happened after the beta2 ISO had been released. So the solution I posted as an answer is not a workaround; it just points the OP to what he can do to get the package with the fix.

Comment: @KazWolfe: As regards 17.04 there are several questions about it already, for instance [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904769/no-indian-and-bengali-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu-17-04).

Comment: If the accepted answer solved OP's problem then this was an issue that's specific to the incomplete pre-release status of Ubuntu 17.10 which is exactly why it's off topic here. **I'm voting to keep this question closed.**

Comment: @DavidFoerster: That's a valid reason to keep it closed IMO. The reasons Kaz mentioned are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Malayalam (and a bunch of other Indic scripts) were added after the beta 2 release, so probably running these commands will fix it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```